# How to setup an SSL encrypted MySQL connection with Doctrine2 in PHP (not Symfony, not Doctrine1)

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, doctrine-orm

I am having a hard time finding documentation / examples of how to setup an SSL encrypted connection with Doctrine2 to MySQL. I'm not using Symfony, so looking for the pure PHP path.

What I'm stuck on is basically how to convey the MYSQL_CLIENT_SSL (or MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL) flag, and the path to the ca certificate. I can live with not verifying the certificate, but I can't live with not encrypting the connection for this task.

On the command line this would be done similar to this:

```
mysql --ssl-verify-server-cert --ssl-ca=/mysql-ssl-certs/ca-cert.pem --ssl -h host [etc]
```

In pure php using the mysql extension I think it would look something like:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass, false, MYSQL_CLIENT_SSL);
```

With mysqli (i think) it would be something like this:

```
$db = mysqli_init(); 
$db->ssl_set(null, null, $cert, null, null); 
$db->real_connect($host, $user, $pass, $dbname);
```

The question is, how do I do this with Doctrine2? Is it even possible? How do I modify the initialization for Doctrine2 to do this?

```
$DOCTRINE2_DB = array(
  'driver'      => 'pdo_mysql',
  'host'        => $host,
  'user'        => $user,
  'password'    => $pass,
  'dbname'      => $dbname,
  'unix_socket' => $sockpath,
);
$DOCTRINE2_EM = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($DOCTRINE2_DB, $DOCTRINE2_CONFIG);
$EM =& $DOCTRINE2_EM; // for brevity & sanity
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to add an additional parameter driverOptions and set the appropiate SSL configuration for PDO

https://www.php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-mysql.php#pdo-mysql.constants

```
$DOCTRINE2_DB = array(
    'driver'      => 'pdo_mysql',
    'host'        => $host,
    'user'        => $user,
    'password'    => $pass,
    'dbname'      => $dbname,
    'unix_socket' => $sockpath,
    'driverOptions' => array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => '...',
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => '...',
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY => '...'
    )
);
```

I can't test it but looking at the code [here](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/89c7b527c70d7a12bfdb41c0e88e4ac25e966b6d/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DriverManager.php#L93) I think it should work

[EDIT BY ASKER:]
Here is how it worked for me:

```
$DOCTRINE2_DB = array(
    'driver'      => 'pdo_mysql',
    'host'        => $host,
    'user'        => $user,
    'password'    => $pass,
    'dbname'      => $dbname,
    'unix_socket' => $sockpath,
    'driverOptions' => array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => '/file/path/to/ca_cert.pem',
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks going to give this a try. According to the php.net page you linked to purely by setting one of those constants it should enable SSL.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm in the comments as well that this solution worked for me. Thanks!